# Textchanged event for dynamically create textbox

Tags: c#, events, textbox, dynamic, textchanged

I have problem like this:
Have some function where I dynamically create TabPage object and textBox control on it.

```
   private void Create()
   {
        TabPage zakladkaTabControl = createTabPage();
        TextBox TB = new TextBox();

        TB.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TB_TextChanged);
    }
```

Now I need to change TabPage name dynamically when I write something in my TextBox control. I have function which supports changing content of the TextBox control:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((TabPage)sender).Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```

It doesn't work because function calling only to the TextBox object and not the TextBox and TabPage. I know a solution for objects created statically, but dynamically? For several hours I can not find a solution.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: you are registering TB_TextChanged and showing code for textBox1_TextChanged method. Is there a mismatch? Soln of Hans should work but I'm not sure exactly what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
var box = (TextBox)sender;
var page = (TabPage)sender.Parent;
page.Text = box.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent TabPage, you can walk up the control hierarchy until you find it:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    Control ctl = tb.Parent;
    while (ctl != null && !(ctl is TabPage))
    {
        ctl = ctl.Parent;
    }

    if (parent != null)
    {
        var tp = (TabPage)parent;
        // Change the TabPage name here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make zakladkaTabControl a property of the class rather than a local variable so that you can refer to it from the textBox1_TextChanged method.